# How can set an input time depending of another input time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'm trying to change link the times input. When I choose a hour in the eventStartTime, I would like to  fill, depend of a time passing through the minutesToHours function (in minutes), the eventEndTime (an addition : the eventStartTime + the minutes I've added)

I have tried to do it by myself, but i didn't get any results :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#eventStart').on('input', function () {
            var convertDuration = minuteToHours(6);
            $('#eventEnd').val($(this).val() + moment(convertDuration).format('HH:mm'));
        });
});
function minuteToHours(num) {
            var hours = Math.floor(num / 60);
            var minutes = num % 60;
            return hours + ":" + minutes;
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="form-label" for="eventStart">Heure début</label>
             <input class="form-control" id="eventStart" type="time">
          </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="form-group">
               <label class="form-label" for="eventEnd">Heure Fin</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="eventEnd" type="time">
         </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: @cfarhad Hello, Well here an example : As param in my function I put : 20 (minutes), then I choose 07:35 in the eventStartTime, I want to display in the eventEndTime : 07:55

Comment: Or I choose to add 120 minutes, when I will choose 07:40 in eventStartTime, it will display 9:40 in the eventEndTime

Comment: Do you want to add 120 minutes to any time you choose and display it?

Comment: @cfarhad For example : I want to add 120 minutes. I choose an start hours (the first input), then I want to automatically fill the end hours (the second input) with an addition between the minutes I added and the start hours I choose,